# How do I disable automatic updates for Azure VM extensions?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, dsc

We have a few VMs in Azure and we rely on the [PowerShell DSC extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/08/07/introducing-the-azure-powershell-dsc-desired-state-configuration-extension.aspx) to deploy our code to the machines. I want to make sure that this extension is not updated automatically so that our code that uses functionality from this extension don't break without we knowing about it first.

The problem is that we have some deployment scripts that read the extension's status codes/messages and do custom logic based on them. When the extension was updated from 1.4.0.0 (which is the version that the plugin was on when we first started using it) to the version 1.5.0.0, [some of the status messages changed and our script stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26759691/1946412). This completely broke our deployment process and we had to do an emergency update on our scripts to be compatible with v1.5. Now that version 1.7.0.0 was released the same exact problem happened again. Some new status codes were added and I had to update our scripts or we would not have a working deployment pipeline.

Is it possible to specify a manual update process for these extensions? Their installation and update seem to be completely automated. Ideally, I'd like to be able to update them on a case by case basis after testing our scripts against the newer versions first, so that our deployment process is not halted because of that. Bonus points for anyone who manages to find up to date documentation or some kind of release notes document for this extension in particular, as I could find none... I was just surprised to see that version 1.7 was installed today when I got an error from our script, and was lucky to know exactly where to look for the status changes.

Comment: Could the down voter and those voting to close the question explain why they are doing it? Why is the question poor?

Comment: You are asking about a setting in Microsoft Azure, and it doesn't have anything to do with programming. You should open a case with Microsoft, or perhaps re-work or scripts/custom logic to deal with automatic upgrades (which would be a completely different question that *might* be on topic here).

Comment: @briantist Ok, fair enough. Would you suggest I post this question in ServerFault instead? Or perhaps someone with enough reputation could move it there?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would consider ServerFault for this, but do check the rules and maybe browse the Azure questions there to see if it would be a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for the DSC extension handler is to update to the latest version. If you want to tie yourself down to a specific version, then you can do so with the following cmdlet (currently there is no provision from the UI)

Set-AzureVMDscExtension -Version

Please note that we are also try to ensure updates do not cause issues. We are not there yet but we would certainly like to get there so everyone is automatically updated.

Comment: This is great news, I'll try that in a day. Btw, are you part of the development team on the extension? If your intention was not to break things I must say you guys failed very hard so far xD. As I said, both updates broke the code we had that depended on the status codes from the extension. I also tried to find a changelog/release notes document but didn't find anything, Do you have any links to such pages that you could share? I'd like to at least know that there is an updated version if I went the route of fixing the version in our VMs. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yes I am from the development team and we are working towards ensuring that we do not break things. We are not there yet but want to get there asap. Here is a link to our release history [link]http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/11/20/release-history-for-the-azure-dsc-extension.aspx

Comment: That link is very helpful, I'm bookmarking it. Damn, if only I knew about this before I'd already be testing the new features xD. Very grateful for your support Nana, thanks a lot.